# Why sometime all data do not insert in to table through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP 5.6 & MySQL object for connection.  Using UTF-8 character set I have an order table with 20 fields & `order_details` (longtext) is one of them.

I have session of `$_SESSION['cart']` array in PHP and it collects product items details added in cart.

```
$_SESSION["cart"][$value][] = array(
    "product_id" => $result_items["id"],
    "price" => $result_items["price"], 
    "name" => $result_items["name"], 
    "qty" => 1, 
    "ingredient_name" => '', 
    "save_img_name" => '', 
    "size_id" => '', 
    "size_name" => '', 
    "cat_id" => 'offers'
);
```

Before saving to database I serialize the cart array and store in variable

```
@$cart = serialize($_SESSION["cart"]);
$cart=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$cart);
```

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 182
                    [price] => 9.90
                    [name] => Frutti di Mare
                    [qty] => 1
                    [ingredient_name] => Katkarapu_Simpukka_Tonnikala
                    [save_img_name] => 5acb867ed018b.jpg
                    [spices] => 
                    [size_id] => 36
                    [size_name] => Norm
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 192
                    [price] => 11.90
                    [name] => Kylmäsavulohi Pizza
                    [qty] => 1
                    [ingredient_name] => Aurajuusto_Herkkusieni_kylmäsavulohi_Tilli
                    [save_img_name] => 5acb8c36709ea.jpg
                    [spices] => 
                    [size_id] => 36
                    [size_name] => Norm
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 181
                    [price] => 9.90
                    [name] => Frutti di Mare
                    [qty] => 1
                    [ingredient_name] => Mussel_Shrimp_Tuna
                    [save_img_name] => 5acb867ed018b.jpg
                    [size_id] => 35
                    [size_name] => Normal
                    [cat_id] => 
                    [spices] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 191
                    [price] => 11.90
                    [name] => Cold smoked salmon pizza
                    [qty] => 1
                    [ingredient_name] =>  Cold smoked salmon_Blue cheese_Mushroom_Til
                    [save_img_name] => 5acb8c36709ea.jpg
                    [size_id] => 35
                    [size_name] => Normal
                    [cat_id] => 
                    [spices] => 
                )

        )

)

Output of $_SESSION["cart"] array
```

Pass this variable in insert query to store in database in `cart_details` field.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO orders SET sub_total = '".$sub_total."', 
delivery_charges= '".$delivery_charges."', discount= '".$discount."', 
discount_rate= '".$discount_rate."', order_details= '".$cart."', 
city= '".$city."', zipcode= '".$zipcode."', tax= '".$tax."', 
tax_rate= '".$tax_rate."', picktime= '".$picktime."', user_id= '".$user_id."', 
address= '".$address."', booked_on = '".$booked_on ."', payment_date = '".$booked_on ."', 
extra_delivery_charges = '".$extra_delivery_charges ."', status= 0,  
paymentmode='".$paymentmode."', reg_offer_amount='".$reg_offres."',  
delivery_type='".$delivery_type."', payment_status='".$payment_status."',  
distance='".$distance_in."',  additional_info= '".$additional_info."', 
building_no= '".$building_no."', browser_detail= '".$browser_detail."', 
coupon_discount= '".$coupon_value."', session_id= '".$session_id."'";
```

Comment: It might be a wrong data type used, so that the length of value it can hold is not enough for the type of data you are trying to insert. Hard to say having the little information you gave. Could you provide a more detailed description of your issue?

Comment: Please provide an example of the exact SQL insert query you're trying to execute.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to upgrade as soon as possible to PHP 7.

Comment: Where is your code?  What does `$_SESSION['cart']` look like?  Can you reproduce it with a particular `$_SESSION['cart']`?  You will get a better response here if you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it is all we can do is guess because you have not shown us enough detail (code!) to help.

Comment: @Don't Panic code is mentioned in question

Comment: @d-rybchenko data type is "longtext" and it is more enough for it

Comment: 1) There is no `cart_details` field in your SQL. 2) Why are you suppressing errors in `@$cart`?  Something is failing, you should not be hiding errors. 3) What is `$value` in `$_SESSION["cart"][$value]`?

Comment: @Don't Panic cart_details is order_details and output also mentioned now in question